# import java.util.Random does not exist

Tags: java, random, import

New on Eclipse and learning the Java basics. I'm fond of PHP so I don't really have problems with the syntax, but when I try to use `rand = new Random`, the `Random` goes red even if I declare `import java.util.Random` on the top of my class.  Am I missing something?

```
import java.util.Random;
    public class Forge {
    int chance = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
       rand = new Random;
    }
}
```

Random goes red and also my **CTRL+SHIFT+O** does not work when I try to import something on my class.

Comment: `Random rand = new Random();` ?

Comment: you have forgotten to add `()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating object you need to do

```
Random rand=new Random();
```

You have forgotten to add `()` in this line `rand = new Random;`

Comment: didnt see that, somehow i feel stupid for posting this question, one of the reasons i hate being dyslexic

Comment: @Viscocent It happens for learners,I was also facing similar problems when I was new to java.You will gain knowledge in time

Answer (score 2):

Here you haven't created an object from the Random class correctly.

**Correct syntax:**

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

**Solution**

```
import java.util.Random;
    public class Forge {
    int chance = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Random rand = new Random();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

The Random() is the call to the default constructor for Random.

Anything in place of the Random before the rand cannot be lower in the hierarchy of inheritance or it will have to be type casted.